# Why do acids ionize in solution if they are covalently bonded?

Tags: acid-base, bond, aqueous-solution, covalent-compounds

Maybe I am wrong, but I thought acids were covalently bonded since hydrogen doesn't form ionic compounds. For example, wouldn't $\ce{HCl}$ look like:

[image: structure of HCl]

Since the electrons are shared, why does it break into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ in solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Because it is energetically favourable ($\Delta{G}<0$) for hydrogen chloride to react with water to form hydronium( $\ce{ H3O+}$) and chloride ions.

Remember that $\ce{ H+}$ does not exist as $\ce{ H+}$ in water, but rather as $\ce{ H3O+}$.

Comment: Why is it energetically favorable for this reaction to occur? Is the enthalpy very low (negative), or is the entropy very high, or both?

Comment: Both. for most cases, dissolving a compound to form an acid releases heat (negative enthalpy). Also, entropy is increased due to the addition of chloride (and also the breaking of H-Cl bond).

Comment: Typically the curved arrows are used for electron pair transfers.

Answer (score 1):

Your are right. But you have to remember that the bond between hydrogen and chlorine (for example) is covalent polar one. When you introduce this molecule into water which is a polar solvent with a dipole moment of 1.85 D, the polarization of the molecule $\ce{HCl}$ increases. We  have then two solvated ions  $\ce{H_3O^+}$  and and  $\ce{Cl^-}$. And  as water has also a high dielectric constant  $\epsilon_r=80$, the electrostatic force between  $\ce{H_3O^+}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$ will decrease by a factor of 80. So, the the bond between $\ce{H_3O^+}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$ will weaken  and we have ionization of the acid.